# Is it normal for graduate tuition to be much cheaper than undergraduate tuition?

Tags: tuition

The [undergraduate tuition](https://www.rochester.edu/adminfinance/bursar/RCFees16-17.html) in the University of Rochester is $49260 per year.

On the other hand, [graduate tuition](https://www.rochester.edu/adminfinance/bursar/PDFs/GradFees2016-17.pdf) adds up to only $27684 (18 credit hours).

Am I missing something?

Comment: What kind of graduate student? If for example you mean a STEM PhD student, then "tuition" is just a made-up number that's used in sketchy accounting. If any money transfers hands, it's from one part of the university to another, and it has no meaning to the student. The student in the end is *paid* a stipend, and this is all that matters.

Comment: For my case, it's STEM MS, so tuition still matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard full-time undergraduate course load is 16 credits per semester (32 credits per year). (See [here](https://www.rochester.edu/college/ccas/AdviserHandbook/DegreeReq.html): the four-year undergraduate degree requires 128 credits.) The flat-rate cost for the example you have cited comes out to $1539.375/credit.

The standard full-time graduate course load is 9 credits per semester (18 credits per year). The flat-rate cost for the example you have cited comes out to $1538/credit.

For the school you have used as your example, the per-credit [fee for part-time students](https://www.rochester.edu/adminfinance/bursar/parttime.htm) is $1538/credit in most cases.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that. Still, normally the difference is no more than a few thousand dollars at other schools. I suppose Rochester just do things differently.

Comment: @Quevun I don't know what "other schools" you are referring to, but it's pretty normal in the US for tuition fees to depend on the standard course load, and for graduate credit hours to cost approximately the same or a little more than undergraduate credit hours.

Comment: I mean the total cost that adds up over a year is usually about the same for both graduate and undergraduate tuition.